How can I limit the scroll on mobile until the end of a container using CSS or JavaScript?
I have started to build a mobile menu just like the one on apple.com using the method from the video below:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eTvNoS2yqd4
All is great, except one thing. I can't figure out how to stop the scrolling at the end of each container. Basically the scroll goes along with the homepage underneath and I end up with a huge empty space if visitors choose to scroll it.
I would love to be able to scroll just until the content from each submenu finishes, not longer. For the container I am using position:absolute instead of fixed. I know that "fixed" would block the scrolling, but I still need it for the containers with multiple items.
I have tried using overflow, a combination of overflow-x and overflow-y, but got no result. I've tried to create a no-scroll class, but this blocks the scrolling on all containers, which is fine, except on those where I need scrolling, as the submenu items are too many to fit into the viewport.
Below is a link with a video of the menu, to better understand my problem.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lKspXaooDa_O3UTRdI5gorF6XTUGG6dE/view?usp=drive_link
My question is: do you have any idea on how to limit the scrolling to the end of the content of each container, just like on the mobile submenus on apple.com? If it helps, below is the full code that I've made for this menu.
Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.
type 
<head>
  <style>
    [id^='meniu'] {
      opacity: 0;
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      overflow:hidden;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      left: 0; 
      z-index: 9999;

    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
      // Function to toggle visibility for a specific element by ID
      function toggleVisibility(elementId, show) {
        var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
        if (element) {
          element.style.display = show ? 'flex' : 'none';
          element.style.opacity = show ? '1' : '0';
          if (show) {
            document.documentElement.classList.add('no-scroll');
            document.body.classList.add('no-scroll');
          } else {
            document.documentElement.classList.remove('no-scroll');
            document.body.classList.remove('no-scroll');
          }
        }
      }

      // Function to close all elements starting with 'meniu'
      function closeAllMenus() {
        document.querySelectorAll("[id^='meniu']").forEach(function(menu) {
          toggleVisibility(menu.id, false);
        });
      }

      // Show meniu_principal when Link_open is clicked
      document.getElementById('Link_open').addEventListener('click', function() {
        closeAllMenus();
        toggleVisibility('meniu_principal', true);
      });

      // Adapted to handle any ID beginning with Link_close_all to close all menus
      document.querySelectorAll("[id^='Link_close_all']").forEach(function(btn) {
        btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
          closeAllMenus();
        });
      });

      document.getElementById('Link_open_tratamente_faciale').addEventListener('click', function() {
        closeAllMenus();
        toggleVisibility('meniu_tratamente_faciale', true);
      });
      document.getElementById('Link_open_tratamente_faciale2').addEventListener('click', function() {
        closeAllMenus();
        toggleVisibility('meniu_tratamente_faciale', true);
      });

      document.getElementById('Link_open_barbati').addEventListener('click', function() {
        closeAllMenus();
        toggleVisibility('meniu_barbati', true);
      });
      document.getElementById('Link_open_barbati2').addEventListener('click', function() {
        closeAllMenus();
        toggleVisibility('meniu_barbati', true);
      });

      document.getElementById('Link_open_facial_barbati').addEventListener('click', function() {
        closeAllMenus();
        toggleVisibility('meniu_facial_barbati', true);
      });
      document.getElementById('Link_open_facial_barbati2').addEventListener('click', function() {
        closeAllMenus();
        toggleVisibility('meniu_facial_barbati', true);
      });
      document.getElementById('Link_open_tratamente_corporale').addEventListener('click', function() {
        closeAllMenus();
        toggleVisibility('meniu_tratamente_corporale', true);
      });
      document.getElementById('Link_open_tratamente_corporale2').addEventListener('click', function() {
        closeAllMenus();
        toggleVisibility('meniu_tratamente_corporale', true);
      });

      document.getElementById('Link_open_servicii').addEventListener('click', function() {
        closeAllMenus();
        toggleVisibility('meniu_servicii', true);
      });
      document.getElementById('Link_open_servicii2').addEventListener('click', function() {
        closeAllMenus();
        toggleVisibility('meniu_servicii', true);
      });

      document.getElementById('Link_open_facial_design').addEventListener('click', function() {
        closeAllMenus();
        toggleVisibility('meniu_facial_design', true);
      });
      document.getElementById('Link_open_facial_design2').addEventListener('click', function() {
        closeAllMenus();
        toggleVisibility('meniu_facial_design', true);
      });

      document.getElementById('Link_open_botox').addEventListener('click', function() {
        closeAllMenus();
        toggleVisibility('meniu_botox', true);
      });
      document.getElementById('Link_open_botox2').addEventListener('click', function() {
        closeAllMenus();
        toggleVisibility('meniu_botox', true);
      });

      document.getElementById('Link_open_botox3').addEventListener('click', function() {
        closeAllMenus();
        toggleVisibility('meniu_botox_barbati', true);
      });
      document.getElementById('Link_open_botox4').addEventListener('click', function() {
        closeAllMenus();
        toggleVisibility('meniu_botox_barbati', true);
      });

      document.getElementById('Link_open_signature').addEventListener('click', function() {
        closeAllMenus();
        toggleVisibility('meniu_signature', true);
      });
      document.getElementById('Link_open_signature2').addEventListener('click', function() {
        closeAllMenus();
        toggleVisibility('meniu_signature', true);
      });

      document.getElementById('Link_open_dermatologie').addEventListener('click', function() {
        closeAllMenus();
        toggleVisibility('meniu_dermatologie', true);
      });
      document.getElementById('Link_open_dermatologie2').addEventListener('click', function() {
        closeAllMenus();
        toggleVisibility('meniu_dermatologie', true);
      });

      document.getElementById('Link_open_ginecologie').addEventListener('click', function() {
        closeAllMenus();
        toggleVisibility('meniu_ginecologie', true);
      });
      document.getElementById('Link_open_ginecologie2').addEventListener('click', function() {
        closeAllMenus();
        toggleVisibility('meniu_ginecologie', true);
      });

      document.getElementById('Link_open_chirurgie').addEventListener('click', function() {
        closeAllMenus();
        toggleVisibility('meniu_chirurgie_plastica', true);
      });
      document.getElementById('Link_open_chirurgie2').addEventListener('click', function() {
        closeAllMenus();
        toggleVisibility('meniu_chirurgie_plastica', true);
      });

      document.getElementById('Link_open_stomatologie').addEventListener('click', function() {
        closeAllMenus();
        toggleVisibility('meniu_stomatologie', true);
      });
      document.getElementById('Link_open_stomatologie2').addEventListener('click', function() {
        closeAllMenus();
        toggleVisibility('meniu_stomatologie', true);
      });

      document.getElementById('Link_open_vitaminoterapie').addEventListener('click', function() {
        closeAllMenus();
        toggleVisibility('meniu_vitaminoterapie', true);
      });
      document.getElementById('Link_open_vitaminoterapie2').addEventListener('click', function() {
        closeAllMenus();
        toggleVisibility('meniu_vitaminoterapie', true);
      });

      document.getElementById('Link_open_body_design').addEventListener('click', function() {
        closeAllMenus();
        toggleVisibility('meniu_body_design', true);
      });
      document.getElementById('Link_open_body_design2').addEventListener('click', function() {
        closeAllMenus();
        toggleVisibility('meniu_body_design', true);
      });

      document.getElementById('Link_open_body_design3').addEventListener('click', function() {
        closeAllMenus();
        toggleVisibility('meniu_body_design_men', true);
      });
      document.getElementById('Link_open_body_design4').addEventListener('click', function() {
        closeAllMenus();
        toggleVisibility('meniu_body_design_men', true);
      });

      document.getElementById('Link_open_mezoterapii').addEventListener('click', function() {
        closeAllMenus();
        toggleVisibility('meniu_mezoterapii', true);
      });
      document.getElementById('Link_open_mezoterapii2').addEventListener('click', function() {
        closeAllMenus();
        toggleVisibility('meniu_mezoterapii', true);
      });

      document.getElementById('Link_open_mezoterapii3').addEventListener('click', function() {
        closeAllMenus();
        toggleVisibility('meniu_mezoterapii_men', true);
      });
      document.getElementById('Link_open_mezoterapii4').addEventListener('click', function() {
        closeAllMenus();
        toggleVisibility('meniu_mezoterapii_men', true);
      });

      document.getElementById('Link_open_body_botox').addEventListener('click', function() {
        closeAllMenus();
        toggleVisibility('meniu_body_botox', true);
      });
      document.getElementById('Link_open_body_botox2').addEventListener('click', function() {
        closeAllMenus();
        toggleVisibility('meniu_body_botox', true);
      });

      document.getElementById('Link_open_body_botox3').addEventListener('click', function() {
        closeAllMenus();
        toggleVisibility('meniu_body_botox_men', true);
      });
      document.getElementById('Link_open_body_botox4').addEventListener('click', function() {
        closeAllMenus();
        toggleVisibility('meniu_body_botox_men', true);
      });

      // Setup for any click on IDs starting with Link_close_sub to show only Menu_main
      document.querySelectorAll("[id^='Link_close_sub']").forEach(function(link) {
        link.addEventListener('click', function() {
          closeAllMenus(); // First, close all menus
          toggleVisibility('meniu_principal', true); // Then, show Menu_main
        });
      });

      // Setup for any click on IDs starting with Link_close_sub to show only Menu_main
      document.querySelectorAll("[id^='Link_facial']").forEach(function(link) {
        link.addEventListener('click', function() {
          closeAllMenus(); // First, close all menus
          toggleVisibility('meniu_tratamente_faciale', true); // Then, show Menu_main
        });
      });

      // Setup for any click on IDs starting with Link_close_sub to show only Menu_main
      document.querySelectorAll("[id^='Link_corporale']").forEach(function(link) {
        link.addEventListener('click', function() {
          closeAllMenus(); // First, close all menus
          toggleVisibility('meniu_tratamente_corporale', true); // Then, show Menu_main
        });
      });

      // Setup for any click on IDs starting with Link_close_sub to show only Menu_main
      document.querySelectorAll("[id^='Link_servicii']").forEach(function(link) {
        link.addEventListener('click', function() {
          closeAllMenus(); // First, close all menus
          toggleVisibility('meniu_servicii', true); // Then, show Menu_main
        });
      });

      // Setup for any click on IDs starting with Link_close_sub to show only Menu_main
      document.querySelectorAll("[id^='Link_barbati']").forEach(function(link) {
        link.addEventListener('click', function() {
          closeAllMenus(); // First, close all menus
          toggleVisibility('meniu_barbati', true); // Then, show Menu_main
        });
      });
    });
    

  </script>
</body>
</html>
here


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

^ it looks like you've included CSS and JS, but it also needs your HTML body in order for people to see what's going on

Please share your code on the codesandbox.. so I will solved this issues

Sorry for not being more specific. The website is built in Wordpress using the Elementor page builder. The code that I've added above is the entire code that I've created for the menu, it was added using an HTML widget. I have created all the submenu containers using Elementor, then I have targeted them using the code above.
If it helps, I can give you the site. It is https://staging.deliathiess.com, access password is beepbeep
